# $\sin(\pi x)\geq\frac{x}{2}$ for $0\leq x\leq \frac34$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

How can I prove that $\sin(\pi x)\geq\dfrac{x}{2}$ for $0\leq x\leq \dfrac34$? It's very simple-looking, but the $\sin x\leq x$ doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that equality holds at $0$, and the inequality still holds at $x = \frac 3 4$, since

$$\sin \frac{3\pi}{4} = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} > \frac 3 8$$

On the other hand, the function $$f(x) = \sin \pi x - \frac x 2$$

is concave down, so it lies above the line connecting the points $(0, 0)$ and $\left(\frac 3 4, f\left(\frac 3 4\right)\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see this graphically. Since $\sin(\pi x)$ is concave in the interval $[0,3/4]$, we have
$$\underbrace{\sin(\pi x)}_{\sin \text{curve}} \geq \overbrace{\dfrac{\sin(\pi \cdot 3/4)}{3/4} x}^{\text{line joining 0 and 3/4}} = \dfrac{4 \sin(\pi/4)}3 x = \dfrac{2\sqrt2}{3}x$$